# How can I get stronger while involved in other physical activities?

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, home-exercise

I am training for some time now but I don't feel like my schedule is in balance.

I switch between:

Scheme 1:

- Neck Flexion (neck)
- Lying Neck Extension (neck)
- Arnold Press (shoulder)
- Rear Lateral Raise (shoulder)
- Bench Press (chest)
- Incline Bench Press (chest)

Scheme 2:

- Bent-over Row (back)
- Curl (bicep)
- Kickback (tricep)
- One Arm Triceps Extension (tricep)
- Wrist Curl (wrist)
- Situp Crunches (waist)

I alternate between these and exercise 3 times a week.

I setup this scheme myself and since I'm not 100% happy with it I started reading about the `Stronglifts` 5x5 method. This seems very appealing to my but I cannot implement this because:

- riding 40km 5 times a week
- running 5km a week
- 1 martial arts trainings a week (and some exercises at home)

My legs are really pushed to the limit by this so I can take some training there but not loads of it.

Beside this I don't have enough money to get myself a gym pass and I'm limited to my home bench (just a small bench) 2 hand hand halters and a basic bar.

I also can't find any decent site that helps me build a schedule for free so I hope to get some advice here.

edit: My goals for weight training is to get stronger and build up figure in general.

Comment: What are your goals?  Are you working to get stronger in order to improve your martial arts performance?  If so, have you talked to your martial arts instructor about possible suggestions?

Comment: @Tip_Top edited, my goals are gaining strength and build figure

Comment: Your routine does not fit your goals.  You are doing far too much cardio.  If your goal is to get stronger, I would suggest sticking to the Stronglifts program without cardio for the first few weeks, then adding cardio gradually (1-2 sessions per week).  If the cardio starts to negatively impact your strength gains, then ease back on the cardio.  Your figure is largely a result of your diet.

Comment: @Tip_Top :  I can only cut back on my running. My biking is to work and back, and i have no alternative for this.

Comment: No legs in your workout

Comment: What sports do you play?  What is your level at those sports?

Comment: Mostly bicycling - avarage level, 200km/week at 29km/h avarage. Weight lifting, low level (50kg bench press ..), Wing Chun, avarage level(practicing 3years)

Comment: So you are asking if your program maximizes your biking and Wing Chun?

Comment: no, i want my program to be seperate from the pother sports. To increase my strength

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must do legs in your workout.  Think of your body as a growing tree.  Have you ever seen a tree with a skinny trunk and huge branches?

As your legs get stronger and you strengthen your core the rest of your body will fall in place - you have an upper body workout (that is probably not optimal but I don't know enough about you to recommend something exactly).  With the equipment you have (don't have) I would do lots of deadlifts, light squats (you will have to clean the bar up and lift over your head - I know this sucks but a lot of home lifters have to do it - really light weight), good mornings (do a set of good mornings after a set of squats while the bar is there), and dumbbell squats.  I personally would incorporate star bursts or frog jumps with this workout if I didn't have the weights to push myself.

You can start with one set of each every other day (deadlifts should be first and you should be trying to lift as much as you can according to your plan eventually).  And work up to a full legs/lower back workout that you are doing twice a week.  I don't think once a week is enough given lack of equipment if you want results quickly.

I know this will hurt.  It will suck having to ride your bikes some days.  But you need to start slow with the legs and work your way up - and your bike rides will actually be easier in the long run.

As for the running 5km a week is not too much.  Even with the biking.  I would shoot for more but up to you.

What can you expect.  Well once you get used to your core/leg routine you can work on form and explosion.  You will get stronger and you can get serious muscle tone if the intensity is right.  However given the lack of weights/equipment you will probably plateau faster and easier.  But then again I would work on intensity level and slowly increasing the weight.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a list of bodybuilding work, rather than strength training. You should consider a strength workout once or twice a week. You could do a few sets each of chin-ups, dips, bench presses, overhead presses, and even squats and deadlifts.

Comment: He doesn't have the equipment for it.

Comment: He has a bench and a bar, and if he doesn't have a pull-up bar then he should get one. I suspect he has two chairs for dips.